# sudo su - immediately after SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, su

I have this SSH config file for root:

```
User    ansible
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
PermitLocalCommand yes
LocalCommand='/bin/sudo /bin/su -'
IdentityFile    /root/.ssh/ansible_onlinux
```

(FYI I've tried with ' " without anything, same issue)
When I ssh to the server I got this error.

```
/bin/bash: /bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

However if I run the command on the machine it works.
Where is the problem?

I want to ssh from my ubuntu on windows (WSL) to a centos server.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `/usr/bin/sudo`? That's where it is on my Debian servers.

Comment: What do you mean by "after SSD"? Is that a typo for SSH?

Comment: Yes, typo, corrected. So the machine where I try to ssh the sudo is in the /usr/bin/sudo but the machine where I want to ssh it is /bin/sudo. I want to ssh from my ubuntu on windows (WSL) to a centos server.

Comment: `LocalCommand` is executed on the client, not the server. I can't tell which is the client or server in your description.

Comment: The documentation of `LocalCommand` says that it shouldn't be used for interactive commands. Why are you trying to run `sudo su -` with this?

Comment: Ok, so the localcommand related parameters needs to be on the server where I connect, correct?

Comment: Because I login to the server and I need to be root to perform commands so I need to type sudo su - always in every server.

Comment: Use `RemoteCommand` to specify a command to run on the server.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the working config.

```
User    ansible
IdentityFile    /root/.ssh/ansible_onlinux
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
LogLevel=error
RequestTTY force
RemoteCommand sudo su -
```

Comment: Where is this supposed to go? If I put this into ~/.ssh/config the ssh client fails with "RemoteCommand"

Comment: I can answer myself. My ssh client does not support it. The minimum version is OpenSSH 7.6. Version can be checked using `ssh -V`
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354594/remote-command-in-ssh-config-file

Comment: This should go under a `Host` section, like so: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166920/ssh-gateway-in-ssh-config?rq=1